# React Native app with Expo. APK installs but can't open - Entry points?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

I've built the app with android studio. When I download the app-debug.apk and install it in my android, it doesn't allow me to open it and I can't see it in the menu either.

I've been researching with the help I received here about [Entry Points](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/)

so I tried

**App.js**

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

// (1) import Expo from "expo"
//Tried adding this one, with the following (1) lines in the other files
import {AppLoading, registerRootComponent } from "expo";

function App() {
  return (
<View/>
  );
}

export default registerRootComponent(App);

/*I've tried these:
export default registerRootComponent(App);
//
export default App;
//
registerRootComponent(App);
export default App
//
(1) export default Expo.registerRootComponent(App);
*/
```

**app.json**

```js
{ 
//(1)
  "expo": {
    "entryPoint": "./src/app/App.js",
[...]
}
```

**node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js**

```js
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';

import App from '../../App';
//I've already checked and it is the correct directory for App.js
registerRootComponent(App);
```

**package.json**

```js
{
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
//I've also tried 
//"main": "./App.js",
[...]
}
```

I have no clue what is wrong with this. I've been told to look about XML and Entry Points, but I don't know which direction to go. Please excuse my ignorance, my intention is not to annoy anyone, but I really don't know where to go from here. If anyone could point me the documentation I should read it would be great. I can't find my issue anywhere.

Does it being an expo app make a difference? Is it a react native issue? Is it an android studio issue? Is the problem within the gradle files and I'm aiming for the wrong target?

I don't know if it is relevant but here's my gradle files:

**app/build.gradle**

```js
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.multicobertura"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**project/build.gradle**

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**manifest**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.multicobertura">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Multicobertura">
<!--I have tried this solution but ".NewEntryPoint" and "@string/title_activity_second" show in red.-->
        <!-- <activity
            android:name=".NewEntryPoint"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If there's anything else I should've added please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using expo and trying to build with ANDROID STUDIO. See [EXPO BUILDING STANDALONE APPS](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/)